# Adding button to SimplePanel results in error

Tags: gwt, button, user-interface

I am performing the following action in GWT

```
public class FooPanel extends SimplePanel {
    private String url;

    public FooPanel () {
        super(DOM.createAnchor());
        Button button = new Button();
        button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                foo();
            }
        });
        add(button);
    }
}
```

however when I run the code I get the following error

```
SimplePanel can only contain one child widget
```

However Button is a single widget so I am not sure what the problem is? The problem doesn't occur if i don't add the button

Comment: That code snippet doesn't seem to be correct, you have a constructor for `ContentLinkModifierPanel`, but the class is called `FooPanel`. Is that just a typo or is there something missing?

Comment: It's a typo, I'll edit

Comment: Its working for me. No error.

Comment: Are you adding anything outside `FooPanel` class?

Comment: Why are you calling `super(DOM.createAnchor());`?

Comment: by default its added to `div` tag as it call `this(DOM.createDiv());` internally for default constructor. if you add `super(DOM.createAnchor());` then it will be added in `a` (anchor) tag.

Comment: @jonatzin Are you sure the error you get is caused by this line (`add(button);`) ?

Comment: No I checked again it doesn't happen there my mistake

Comment: **Don't** extend any class until and unless you are modifying the existing logic.

Comment: **Favor Composition over Inheritance**

Comment: @Braj You mean "favor"? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at source code of `SimplePanel#add()` to analyze this error.

```
@Override
public void add(Widget w) {
    // Can't add() more than one widget to a SimplePanel.
    if (getWidget() != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("SimplePanel can only contain one child widget");
    }
    setWidget(w);
}
```

Now its clear from the source code that **you have already added a widget in `SimplePanel`**.

Call `SimplePanel#getWidget()` to get the already added widget.

---

Look at the source code of default constructor if `SimplePanel` class. It might help you to understand that how `SimplePanel` enclose the widget inside it.

```
/**
 * Creates an empty panel that uses a DIV for its contents.
 */
public SimplePanel() {
    this(DOM.createDiv());
}
```

Comment: Thanks the error actually comes from a later point in the code

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
super(DOM.createAnchor());
```

You don't need it.

You can simply use your Button in your code, or extend a Button widget. Adding a Button to a SimplePanel does not offer any benefits.

Comment: According to the last comment from the OP, there is no issue. Still, putting a Button inside a link makes no sense.

Comment: Yes I agree with you.

Answer (score -1):

Try with `setWidget(button);` instead of `add(button);`

Comment: I have just created a project, and tested on it, and it works like a charm

Comment: Probably you are adding later more widgets in your code. Check it out.

Comment: @apanizo `add()` internally calls `setWidget()`. Look at my post.

Comment: I know. I have just followed the implemented examples i.e FocusPanel or ScrollPanel. It was about consistency.

Comment: @apanizo once again `add()` internally calls `setWidget()` hence calling `setWidget()` instead of `add()` will make no difference.

Comment: @Braj, and I told you, that I did it intentionally, because it is the same way that ScrollPanel and FocusPanel (instances of SimplPanel) do.

Comment: @Baz, it does not answer the question, because I tried it (third comment) and the code was fine. So I left the code in that way, for keeping consistency. But anyway, both you are right. Thanks anyway for your time!